# google maps load error "google" undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps

ok, I have a problem on this when loading the maps, this part will shows "google" as `undefined`.

```
var polyline = [
    new Google.map.LatLng(3.032617, 101.376),
    new Google.map.LatLng(3.03255, 101.3759),
    new Google.map.LatLng(3.032467, 101.3758),
    new Google.map.LatLng(3.031867, 101.3753),
    new Google.map.LatLng(3.0318, 101.3753)
];

var polylineopts = {
  path: polyline,
  map: map,
  strokecolor: 'blue',
  strokeopacity: 1.6,
  strokeweight: 3,
  geodesic: true
};

var poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polylineopts);
```

Comment: are u include google map js in head i.e `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>`

Comment: There's no reason in this code to thing `google` would _not_ be `undefined`. Why do you think it should not?

Comment: Are you meaning to use `var poly = new Google.maps.Polyline(polylineopts);` (capitalized)?

Comment: @user2314808 explain your problem clearly.  Put more info of your problem.

Comment: `Google.map != google.maps`

Comment: @Tamil Selvan- yup, here is my code------
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBZtmFIV-wfoMyWK5oHBI7WsIGcSVZeB&sensor=false"> 
</script>

Comment: @JanDvorak- ya, i not sure why got problem as i follow all from network teach

Comment: @ChrisO'Kelly- no, i think is here------var polyline = [
    new Google.map.LatLng(3.032617, 101.376),
    new Google.map.LatLng(3.03255, 101.3759),
    new Google.map.LatLng(3.032467, 101.3758),
    new Google.map.LatLng(3.031867, 101.3753),
    new Google.map.LatLng(3.0318, 101.3753)
];

Comment: @user2314808 - i will post the rest code at below, tq

Comment: @Dr.Molle- sorry, i not so understand about that? tq

Answer (score 2):

I expect the error is "Google" is undefined.  Javascript is case sensitive.

Should be:

```
var polyline = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(3.032617, 101.376),
    new google.maps.LatLng(3.03255, 101.3759),
    new google.maps.LatLng(3.032467, 101.3758),
    new google.maps.LatLng(3.031867, 101.3753),
    new google.maps.LatLng(3.0318, 101.3753)
];

var polylineopts = {
  path: polyline,
  map: map,
  strokecolor: 'blue',
  strokeopacity: 1.6,
  strokeweight: 3,
  geodesic: true
};

var poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polylineopts);
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_Polyline.html)